# Parsing inconsistent XML into pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

this question is about parsing inconsistent XML with the following structure

```
<items>
<item>
    <propertyA>1</propertyA>
    <propertyB>B</propertyB>
    <propertyC>2017</propertyC>
</item>
<item>
    <propertyB>BB</propertyB>
    <propertyD>D-2017</propertyD>
</item>
<item>
    <propertyE>E</propertyE>
    <propertyF>11:25</propertyF>
</item>
</items>
```

Where I'd like each item to be a record in dataframe. Final dataframe should have all the properties A,B,C,D,E,F and records should have NaN or something else in case they dont have these values.

The way I am doing it right now is

```
def load_inconsistent_xml(xml):
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
frames = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for child in root.iter('item'):
    record = []
    headers = []
    for subchild in child:
        headers.append(subchild.tag)
        record.append(subchild.text)

    s2 = pd.Series(record, index=headers)
    df = df.append(s2, ignore_index=true)

if not df.empty:
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
return df
```

As you surely can see, I am doing it by appending new pd.Series to dataframe. The approach seems bulletproof(at least to me :D) and I get my data consistent.

Problem is, it is very inefficient with 100k items it takes long long time.
What would you recommend?

Thank you for your time going over my question. I am newbie to python so I will appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider appending dataframes instead of series with `pd.concat` (a fast row/column binder method) which if columns among the list of dataframes do not align fills NANs. Also, below runs a different parsing with a list of dictionaries casted iteratively to dataframe:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml_str = '''
<items>
<item>
    <propertyA>1</propertyA>
    <propertyB>B</propertyB>
    <propertyC>2017</propertyC>
</item>
<item>
    <propertyB>BB</propertyB>
    <propertyD>D-2017</propertyD>
</item>
<item>
    <propertyE>E</propertyE>
    <propertyF>11:25</propertyF>
</item>
</items>'''

dfs = []

def load_inconsistent_xml(xml):        
    data = []; inner = {}

    root = ET.fromstring(xml)        
    for child in root.iterfind('item'):
        for grandchild in child.iterfind('./*'):            
            inner[grandchild.tag] = grandchild.text

        data.append(inner)
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
        data = []; inner = {}

    finaldf = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(finaldf)

#   propertyA propertyB propertyC propertyD propertyE propertyF
# 0         1         B      2017       NaN       NaN       NaN
# 1       NaN        BB       NaN    D-2017       NaN       NaN
# 2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN         E     11:25
```